# Bash: Find number in strings and add them

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a text file title 'results' and it contains

```
[  PASSED  ] 11 tests.
[  PASSED  ] 590 tests.
[  PASSED  ] 1231 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 4 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 500 tests.
```

I would like to add the PASSED tests and store into a variable. Add the FAILED tests, add them and store into another variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll want to look into `awk`.

Comment: With a `case` statement.

Comment: Your title says `bash:`.  Why do you want to do this in `bash`?  It seems easier to write a small `awk` script, and run store the awk script's output in a bash variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick way using `awk`.

Assuming your test output is in a file called `test.out`:

```
#!/bin/bash
npasses=$(<test.out awk '
/ PASSED / { total += $4 }
END { print total }')

echo number of passing tests: $npasses
```

`<test.out` means `awk` reads from `test.out`.

`/ PASSED / { total += $4 }` appends the forth field to a variable called total, but only for lines matching the regex `PASSED`.

`END { print total }` runs at end of file, and prints the value stored in `total`.

Answer (score 1):

If the log is in a file, you can use

```
regex='\[ (PASSED|FAILED) \] (\d+) tests.'
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || continue
    count=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    case ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} in
        PASSED) let passed += count ;;
        FAILED) let failed += count ;;
    esac
done < input.txt
```

To read directly from another process, replace the last line with

```
done < <( sourcecommand )
```

*Don't* pipe the output of `sourcecommand` in to the while loop; that will cause `passed` and `failed` to be updated in a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash 4's associative arrays:

```
declare -A total
while read _ result _ n _; do
    ((total[$result]+=$n))
done < results
for key in "${!total[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%d\n" "$key" ${total[$key]}
done
```

```
PASSED  1832
FAILED  504
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from Mikel's answer,
You can use `eval` to set the variables directly.

```
eval $(awk '/PASSED/ {pass += $4} /FAILED/ {fail += $4} END {print "pass="pass";fail="fail}' FILE_WITH_DATA)
```

You now have the variables set for you.

```
echo $pass
echo $fail
```